# USB Modem Stopped Working Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, 15.10, network-manager, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I use a MTS MBLAZE modem(created by ZTE) to connect to the Internet. Normally Ubuntu automatically detects the modem and in a few seconds shows a notification that "Mobile Broadband Network. you are connected to the home network" and then I can click on "MTS Broadband connection" to connect to Internet.

Recently this has stopped working. There are two problems that I am facing:

**1. Modem Gets detected but can't connect:** I get the notification that "Mobile Broadband Network. you are connected to the home network" and then I can click on "MTS Broadband connection" but it gives me error that "Disconnected-You are now offline".(Modem works fine in Windows so not due to ISP problem)

**2. Modem does not get detected:** Sometimes the modem isn't detected at all(although it shows up in lsusb). Reconnecting the modem few times usually solves this

Output of lsub when the modem doesn't get detected:

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 19d2:fff5 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

Output of lsub when the modem gets detected:

```
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 19d2:fff1 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

Output of dmesg:

```
[  279.440291] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  279.570655] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=fff5
[  279.570660] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[  279.570662] usb 1-1: Product: ZTE CDMA Tech
[  279.570664] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: ZTE, Incorporated
[  279.570666] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 80d746de0000
[  279.574904] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  279.575315] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  280.575963] scsi 6:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  280.576451] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  280.578783] sr 6:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[  280.579200] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  280.579437] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[  280.580140] sd 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  280.582934] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  290.624145] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  290.992719] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  291.197941] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=fff1
[  291.197946] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[  291.197949] usb 1-1: Product: ZTE CDMA Tech
[  291.197951] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: ZTE, Incorporated
[  291.197952] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 80d746de0000
[  291.248748] option 1-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  291.248882] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  291.249017] option 1-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  291.249104] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  291.249208] option 1-1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  291.249289] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  291.249393] option 1-1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  291.249475] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[  291.249574] option 1-1:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  291.249655] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[  291.249729] usb-storage 1-1:1.5: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  291.249837] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-1:1.5
[  292.260108] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  292.266889] scsi 7:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  292.284370] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[  292.284509] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  292.284833] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[  292.285406] sd 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  292.364092] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I have verified that usb-modeswitch and usb-modeswitch-data are installed. Can't Figure out the problem.